# Redirect of multiple non-www urls to respective www url for a multidomain typo3-installation

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, typo3

we have a typo3-multidomain installation on a hosted server.
domain.de is redirected to www.domain.de/home and
domain-region.de is redirected to www.domain-region.de/home 
(typo3 base url)

**But if I enter the url domain.de/career I'm not redirected to www.domain.de/career but to www.domain.de/home**

I've tested this in .htaccess, but it didn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Additionally we have some https-subdomains for pages including forms, which shouldn't be affected by the www-redirects

Comment: I had once a similar problem: Could you try to add a trailing slash (carreer/).

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to the end of your original TYPO3 ".htaccess":

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?yourdomain\.(it|de|us)$ 
RewriteRule .* http://www.yourdomainmain.com/ [R]
```

Regards 
Pete

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the problem is solved within Typo3
[transfer url parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3b8e.png)